# Script to append JSON structure

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a JSON structure which needs some code to be appended. I tried with SED and bash, that only appends at the end of a string or file, not the end of the structure.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "required": [
    "accounts"
  ],
  "accounts": {
    "required": "account",
    "properties": {
      "account": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "maxItems": 999,
        "required": [
          "scheme",
          "accountType",
          "accountSubType"
        ],
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "scheme": {
              "description": "scheme",
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "schemeName",
                "identification"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "schemeName": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 40
                },
                "identification": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 256
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 70
                },
                "secondaryIdentification": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 35
                }
              }
            },
            "currency": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "iso-4217",
              "pattern": "^[A-Z]{3,3}$",
              "maxLength": 3,
              "example": "EUR"
            },
            "accountType": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "accountSubType": {
              "type": "string",
              "maxLength": 35
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to update the above as

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "required": [
        "accounts"
    ],
    "accounts": {
        "required": "account",
        "properties": {
            "account": {
                "type": "array",
                "minItems": 1,
                "maxItems": 999,
                "required": [
                    "scheme",
                    "accountType",
                    "accountSubType"
                ],
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "scheme": {
                            "description": "scheme",
                            "type": "object",
                            "required": [
                                "schemeName",
                                "identification"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "schemeName": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "maxLength": 40
                                },
                                "identification": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "maxLength": 256
                                },
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "maxLength": 70
                                },
                                "secondaryIdentification": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "maxLength": 35
                                }
                            },
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        },
                        "currency": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "iso-4217",
                            "pattern": "^[A-Z]{3,3}$",
                            "maxLength": 3,
                            "example": "EUR"
                        },
                        "accountType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "accountSubType": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "maxLength": 35
                        }
                    },
                    "additionalProperties": false
                }
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

The difference is at the end of every "properties" section. I have appened it with `"additionalProperties": false`

Is there a way to do this through a script I can check and append all properties with that?

Comment: You could read these into python as dictionaries and apply your transformations there, or you could look at using jq if you want to stick to bash/shell scripts: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Read the JSON in Python as a dictionary using [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) package and then append as follows: `dictionary_name["accounts"]["additionalProperties"] = False` and `dictionary_name["accounts"]["properties"]["account"]["items"]["additionalProperties"] = False`

Comment: ^^ that won't work, you're trying to access a mapping that does not exist

Comment: Please read and understand this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (Requires jq 1.6 because it uses the `walk()` function to traverse the entire structure):

```
$ jq 'walk(if type == "object" and has("properties") then . + { additionalProperties: false } else . end)' your.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter if "additionalProperties" comes after or before "properties"?
If not, you could use sed to add "additionalProperties" before the object "properties" like this:

```
sed -E 's/([[:space:]]*)"properties": {/\1"additionalProperties": false,|\1"properties": {/g'| tr '|' '\n'
```

With you you will get

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "required": [
    "accounts"
  ],
  "accounts": {
    "required": "account",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "account": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "maxItems": 999,
        "required": [
          "scheme",
          "accountType",
          "accountSubType"
        ],
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "scheme": {
              "description": "scheme",
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "schemeName",
                "identification"
              ],
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "properties": {
                "schemeName": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 40
                },
                "identification": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 256
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 70
                },
                "secondaryIdentification": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "maxLength": 35
                }
              }
            },
            "currency": {
              "type": "string",
              "format": "iso-4217",
              "pattern": "^[A-Z]{3,3}$",
              "maxLength": 3,
              "example": "EUR"
            },
            "accountType": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "accountSubType": {
              "type": "string",
              "maxLength": 35
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not encourage people to modify structured data, like json, with sed. This is extremely fragile. Use `jq` instead.